# A way to select a date between two dates in t-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

Say, I have two DATETIME2 columns and I need to select dates between the two. Example: 1/1/2012 08:00 and 1/1/2012 09:00 should produce 1/1/2012 08:30.

I'm trying this:

```
SELECT CAST((CAST(dtOut AS float(53)) + 
       CAST(dtIn AS float(53))) / 2 AS DATETIME2) FROM t;
```

But I get an error that explicit conversion from DATETIME2 is not allowed.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateDiff will find the difference between two dates.

```
 select Dateadd(n, DATEDIFF(n, dtIn, dtOut)/2, dtIn) FROM t
```

As an aside, your method would work if the fields were datetime, not datetime2.

Comment: Very much appreciated! Although really quick, what is the best alternative to n, seconds, minutes?

Comment: n means minutes. If you need seconds precision, use ss - depends on your requirements - see here for options http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I guess, seconds might cause an arithmetic overrun, so I should stick with minutes perhaps...

Comment: Depends on how far these dates are apart. If it's less than 65 years or so, you can use seconds.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know upfront. So you think I'll be safer to stick with minutes then, right?

Comment: Depends whether you're measuring hours worked by someone, or the half life of Uranium :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Out this.

```
  select Dateadd(n, DATEDIFF(n, '1/1/2012 08:00', '1/1/2012 09:00')/2, '1/1/2012 08:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @d1 datetime2, @d2 datetime2
select @d1='1/1/2012 08:00',@d2='1/1/2012 09:00'
 select dateadd(minute,datediff(minute ,@d1,@d2)/2.0,@d1)
```

Answer (score 0):

select dateadd(SECOND,datediff(SECOND ,dtIn,dtOut)/2.0,dtIn)